# Is there a good source for 3rd party QT GUI controls?

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-creator

I have tried to find them through Google but haven't had much luck. I know the number of 3rd party controls is not as big as .NET or Java, but surely there are some out there better than what comes with the library?

Comment: Are you looking for something in particular?  What do you think is missing from the standard Qt widgets?

Comment: I am looking for starters for a property grid control, similar to the one used by QT's GUI designer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290838/best-qt-widget-to-use-for-properties-window

Comment: Thanks, the other biggie is a diagramming component, one that allows you to provide visual graphing, flow charting, etc.

Answer (score 6):

[Qwt](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/) is a source for graphing and technical components and [Solutions Catalog](http://qt.nokia.com/products/appdev/add-on-products/catalog/4) has the property browser as well as many other useful widgets.

Also available are the [Embedded Widget Demos](http://qt.nokia.com/developer/embedded-widget-demos), [ofi-labs](http://gitorious.org/ofi-labs), and [qt-labs](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-labs).

ofi-labs is by a former Qt employee, the others are official.

Edit: Almost forgot, diagramming is covered by this example: [GraphicsView - Diagram Scene](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7-snapshot/graphicsview-diagramscene.html)

Answer (score 3):

free: [qt-apps.org](http://qt-apps.org)

proprietary: [qt-prop.org](http://qt-prop.org/)

there are Widgets and Components categories

Answer (score 2):

<s>It's not exactly third party, but take a look at the [Qt Solutions Catalog](http://qt.nokia.com/products/appdev/add-on-products/catalog/4).</s> Qt Solutions has been discontinued, but there is [an archive](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt-solutions).

There's also [wwWidgets](http://www.wysota.eu.org/wwwidgets/), although I've never had cause to use anything it provides.

For a property editing widget, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290838/best-qt-widget-to-use-for-properties-window).

I doubt you'll find a general purpose diagramming widget that works exactly the way you want it to.  You're probably going to have to do some work yourself on this one.  To get started, take a look at [The Graphics View Framework](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/graphicsview.html).

Take another look at the lists of [widgets](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/qtwidgets-module.html) and [classes](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtdoc/classes.html) Qt provides.  There's an awful lot there, and I rarely find Qt to be deficient.  When I need something special, it's usually not too hard to build a custom widget that does what I need.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the nice Qt Property Browser/Editor: http://doc.trolltech.com/solutions/4/qtpropertybrowser/index.html