# .NET Property Sheet for Qt? Any suggestions?

Tags: c++, qt, parameters, widget, settings

I have some variables I want to change via GUI. The variables are of four types: `bool`, `long long`, `double`, `char *`. Different widgets for different types are wanted:

- QCheckBox for `bool`
- QSpinBox for `long long`
- QDoubleSpinBox for `double`
- QLineEdit for `char*`

Or change `char*` to `std::string` - doesn't matter.

So I need a widget that can draw N lines for N parameters of various types. Each variable can have its name to display in GUI.

I have implemented my own widget, but looking for 'standard solution' of this task. My own impl: http://savepic.net/1742263.png

Want something like Qt Designer's property forms.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290838/best-qt-widget-to-use-for-properties-window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create your own sub-class of QWidget to make your own "property widget" which will have a QLabel and the corresponding Widget for the variable type. then add your custom "property widget" to your application.

for example, if you need to add a line for the bool type, it's class would look something like this:

```
class BoolPropertyWidget : public QWidget
{
  QHBoxLayout layout;
  QLabel label;
public:
  QCheckBox value;  //if you would like to access the actual bool value, you can just use value.isChecked()

  BoolPropertyWidget() {

    //...do necessary adjustments layout, label and value here

    layout.addWidget(&label);
    layout.addWidget(&value);
    setLayout(&layout);
  }
};
```

then if you need to add the property widget to your application, you would just have to create an instance of BoolPropertyWidget and use the addWidget() member function of the layout object in your application.

this will let you create an application with any number of necessary "property widgets" whatever kind it may be.

if ever your application does not resize properly after adding your custom "property widget", try calling adjustSize() on your application.

Answer (score 0):

Industrial Infosystems has a freeware 'value browser' that might be of use: http://www.ii-system.com/soft/vbrowser/vbrowser_en.htm.