# Best Qt Widget to use for properties window... in PySide?

Tags: python, qt, widget, pyside

This question is the exact same as this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290838/best-qt-widget-to-use-for-properties-window) except that I'm looking for such a widget to be used in PySide. Anyone knows some code out there that provide easy-to-reuse property editor widget?

There is the [proposal of using QTreeView or QTableView to build such a widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290838/best-qt-widget-to-use-for-properties-window/1290982#1290982) that is an option with PySide, but this is not a straight forward solution...

Comment: You can always [generate Python binding for the C++ library](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Category:LanguageBindings::PySide::Shiboken::PySide_Binding_Generation_Tutorial). This is actually not that hard if you know some C++.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you would be OK with this, but if you are happy to add the whole of [pyqtgraph](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/) as a dependency, then you might want to try using pyqtgraph's `ParameterTree`.

There is a pretty comprehensive set of examples, just install pyqtgraph and then run:

```
import pyqtgraph.examples
pyqtgraph.examples.run()
```

Launch the ParameterTree example!