# Name of widget used in QT Creator

Tags: widget, qt-creator

What is the name of the widget that is used to produce such a docked widget(which has 2 columns comprises of property and value) in QT Creator on designer mode.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290838/best-qt-widget-to-use-for-properties-window

Comment: @Bill Can you change this comment into an answer so that I can click as the answer. Thanks a lot by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called QtTreePropertyBrowser.

Take a look at this question ([Best Qt Widget to use for properties window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290838/best-qt-widget-to-use-for-properties-window)) for details.