# What code/classes can I use in Qt to implement an Object/Class "Inspector" and Editor

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller, editor, introspection

I'm working on a game engine and the past week I've been reading Qt docs about MVC in Qt. However, I'm stalling because it's unclear to me how to move forward with Qt MVC classes. I'm not using `qmake` or `.pro` files so many tutorials are even more difficult to follow. Regardless, my question is pretty much my title. I have a `QFormLayout` with `QLineEdit` widgets which should correspond to a game object's properties like position, rotation etc. I would like it to be similar to the way Unity3D's inspector works. How can I link each `QLineEdit` to a certain class' field and furthermore how can I more programatically generate a `QLineEdit` for every field of a class being inspected (maybe through reflection)?

Comment: There is no such functionality built-in in Qt but it can be implemented manually. Check out [QtnProperty](https://github.com/lexxmark/QtnProperty) lib. It uses Q_PROPERTY though so you'll have to configure your build system to execute moc.

Comment: Good point to start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290838/best-qt-widget-to-use-for-properties-window

Comment: Thanks I'll look into this.

Comment: The documentation on this is pretty weak not to mention it seems to receive little maintenance. Do you know of any tutorials using QtPropertyBrowsers?

Comment: I'd take a QMetaObject (like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20459764/4742108)), and make an QAbstractListModel with two columns: name(qstring) and value(qvariant). Then show it via some view.

Comment: I've been using the QtPropertyBrowser class but it's been a little difficult. I've managed to get far with it though.